# SqlBulkTools copy identity column exactly

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, sqlbulktools

I'm using the great nuget package here: https://github.com/olegil/SqlBulkTools and am just having a few problems getting a solution that will work. I'm using this over SqlBulkCopy since it is capable of doing upserts (and it works) - the problem I'm having is with the identity column - the identity values get out of sync and then I see many errors (as I would expect).

I'm trying to copy data from source to destination exactly as it is - I don't want the identity column to be different in the target, but I'm having issues with the identity column data becoming completely out of sync when it is copied, which is not what I want.  I'm trying to do a 1-way sync copy for backup purposes (simply copy the data over and be done with it).  I have the KeepIdentity option set, but it doesn't seem to matter\do anything.

I have this code:

```
var settings = new BulkCopySettings();
            settings.BatchSize = 4000;
            settings.SqlBulkCopyOptions = SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity; 

            var bulk = new BulkOperations();
            return bulk.Setup<Submission>()
                .ForCollection(submissions)
                .WithTable(tableName)
                .WithBulkCopySettings(settings)
                .AddAllColumns()
                .BulkInsertOrUpdate()
                .SetIdentityColumn(x => x.Id)
                .MatchTargetOn(x => x.Id)
                .Commit(connection);
```

And I want to copy the Id column exactly as it is in the source, but in the destination it ends up copying the wrong data completely (for example: Id is 1613083 in the source but the same data is ending up as 1613657 in the destination).

Am I better off deleting the identity columns from the destination in order to pull this off, or is there a way to configure this right in the C# code - I tried removing "SetIdentityColumn" but it errors out saying that I need to specify.  Surely there's an equivalent of setting identity insert off when doing such operations?

Comment: Check [EFCore.BulkExtensions](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions), I'm the author.

Answer (score 1):

SqlBulkTools doesn't do identity inserts. SetIdentityColumn() just skips over the column you provide when creating the queries for the upsert ([Source Code](https://github.com/tiagorosendo/SqlBulkTools/blob/104cb5c7a8078c02d4240777182506f6a4504681/SqlBulkTools.NetStandard/Helper/BulkOperationsHelper.cs#L432)). More than likely, your new records were getting inserted out of order, which would cause the behavior you're seeing.

Since you're just using the destination table as a backup, though, I don't see why your table needs to have identity set on the primary key to begin with. The solution I would recommend would be to remove identity on the primary key, then you can remove SetIdentityColumn() and do upserts like normal.

If you absolutely must have identity set, then you'll need to sort your data by Id first and fill in any gaps with default data before you can feed your data to SqlBulkTools.

```
public List<Submission> sortAndFillGaps(List<Submission> submissions)
{
    int lowestId = submissions.Min(s => s.Id);
    int highestId = submissions.Max(s => s.Id);
    for (int i = lowestId + 1; i < highestId; i++)
    {
        if (!submissions.Any(s => s.Id == i))
        {
            submissions.Add(new Submission
                {
                    Id = i
                    // Set defaults for other columns here.
                }
            );
        }
    }
    return submissions.OrderBy(s => s.Id).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit cheesy, but to get around this I simply used ".BulkUpdate()" method to do only updates following a simple two-line statement with SqlBulkCopy, which worked perfectly with the SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity setting) to deal with the inserts.